# My admit/readmit sql Query isnt picking all the readmits

Tags: sql

I created a temp table inside a stored procedure. The query below is supposed to capture the readmits within 30 days. But it is not capturing all the readmits. (there are 3 readmits but it captured only 1).

```
SELECT
       CH3.MedId,
       CH3.Name,
       CH3.Description,
       CH3.StartDate,
       CH3.EndDate,
       CH3.Length_of_Stay,
       CH3. Status,
       CASE
           WHEN CH3.MedId IN
                (
                    SELECT CH1.MedId
                    FROM currentmonth CH1
                        FULL JOIN previousMonth CH2
                            ON CH2.MedId = CH1.MedId
                    WHERE CH1.MedId <> 'NULL'
                          AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, CH2.StartDate, CH1.StartDate)) <= '30'
                ) THEN
               'Readmit'
           ELSE
               'Admit'
       END AS Admit_ReAdmit
FROM currentmonth CH3
ORDER BY CH3.Name;
```

Comment: WHERE CH1.MedId <> 'NULL' <-- Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: what could be wrong then?

Comment: Try `WHERE CH1.MedId IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @jarlh it didnt work

Comment: sample data?  sample of expected output?